# Combine multiple rows data in a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I am trying to pivot a table into a view which would be more easily manipulable with Excel. I am creating views in Sql Server that can be read by the accounting department in order to create stats and other cross-table pivot in Excel.

The table in its current format

```
OccupationId | ProductId | IsGroup | IsAdditionalNight | Price
-------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+------
1            | 47        | 0       | 0                 | 50
2            | 47        | 0       | 1                 | 45
3            | 47        | 1       | 0                 | 30
4            | 47        | 1       | 1                 | 28
```

The View format that I want to expose

```
ProductId | Price | AdditionalNight | GroupPrice | GroupAdditionalNight
----------+-------+-----------------+------------+---------------------
47        | 50    | 45              | 30         | 28
```

How can I achieve that in Sql Server 2008 R2 ? I need the query to be fast since it will be part of a bigger Query (using CTE).

Currently the only way that I am thinking is to include 4 sub queries to get all 4 prices individually, but I don't like the approach and it scan the table 4 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ProductId,
MAX(CASE 
 WHEN IsGroup=0 AND IsAdditionalNight =0 then Price
 END) as [Price],
MAX(CASE 
 WHEN IsGroup=0 AND IsAdditionalNight =1 then Price
 END) as [AdditionalNight],
MAX(CASE 
 WHEN IsGroup=1 AND IsAdditionalNight =0 then Price
 END) as [GroupPrice],
MAX(CASE 
 WHEN IsGroup=1 AND IsAdditionalNight =1 then Price
 END) as [GroupAdditionalNight] 

 FROM table1     
GROUP BY ProductId
```

Or you can do the same using `PIVOT` (Personally I found the syntax of `PIVOT` more complex than approach above, but there is no performance difference, and some people prefer `PIVOT`).

Comment: much cleaner than doing a `PIVOT`

Comment: As simple as that? Demn, I was effectively trying to learn that PIVOT method. Sometime you forget the simple method. Thank you.